# How to send Ctrl+Alt+F[n] to a *nix guest in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am running a CentOS guest in Virtualbox hosted by Ubuntu.

If I hit Ctrl+Alt+F2, for example, it switches the tty in Ubuntu. How to I sent this terminal switch command to the guest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RightCtrl+F2 works. RightCtrl is the "Host Key Combination" in `File > Preferences > Input > Virtual Machine`